# FIle handling and delivery in a Django ELastic Load Balancer deployment

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have a Django app deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk that generates a web page and collects user data for various tables when the user loads the page, clicks a link, etc.

All this data is currently recorded on an RDS database. At periodic intervals, the data for the day is collected (potentially several million rows) and stored in a series of CSV files. The data is then sent to an FTP server to be analysed later. There are also cleaning operations ran to delete data a few days old from the database as well.

I'm thinking that I can potentially remove some overhead and complexity from the project by removing the DB aspect altogether. I shall instead write out the data to files located on the instance, gzip them and send the file over.

A few potential issues occur to me though:

- If my load balancer scales up to more than one instance (currently just one), how can I make sure that each instance receives a command at X hour in the day to get the current file, zip it and send to the FTP?
- How can I uniquely identify which instance the file came from? They have a timestamp attached to the file name but is there an instance ID I can append to it? Is it possible to append to a file over SFTP?

Comment: I think your proposed approach is flawed -- what happens if the instance scales down? You lose your files. A fundamental element of scalable design is to persist your data external to the instance. If you don't want to use a DB, then write to something like an AWS S3 bucket. Secondly, it shouldn't matter the instance the file came from. There should be a unique identifier to tell you to whom the data belongs - how it got there should be irrelevant (other than for troubleshooting).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My second point was flawed, a unique identifier (a uuid or something ) appended to the files would sort that out. I've never used S3 buckets before but is it not impossible to append to a file located on an S3 bucket? I could be getting hundred of clicks per minute and relying on an object external to the instance to store the data may end up being counter-productive.

Comment: I can't speak to your particularities without knowing more. S3 was just an example, but far from the only choice. Kinesis is an option, MongoDB has a fire-forget mode and an expiration date. You would have to research what works best in your situation. The important point is that you want to place your data somewhere that isn't subject to the scaling down of an instance. If latency is your concern, choose some sort of queue or in-memory cache that is very fast to write to from your web server, and use an external app to process it later.